# BeanNameAutoProxyCreator throw NullPointerException

Tags: spring-aop

I use BeanNameAutoProxyCreator to add my interceptor to some bean,but it throw NullPointerException when spring init for some other bean 'sqlSessionFactory'.

I use BeanNameAutoProxyCreator by @Bean annotation.

after BeanNameAutoProxyCreator bean has been created, it throw NullPointerException when spring init for bean 'sqlSessionFactory'.

'sqlSessionFactory' is a bean of mybatis org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.

My spring version is 4.3.7, mybatis-spring is 1.3.1

my code for BeanNameAutoProxyCreator：

```java
@Configuration
public class AbilityRegister {
    @Bean
    public BeanNameAutoProxyCreator beanNameAutoProxyCreator() {       
        String[] abilityBeanNames = ...;
        BeanNameAutoProxyCreator creator = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
        creator.setBeanNames(abilityBeanNames);
        creator.setInterceptorNames("xxInterceptorName");
        creator.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return creator;
    }
}
```

my code for 'sqlSessionFactory':

```xml
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="multipleDataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:*Mapper.xml"/>
</bean>
```

error message:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/application-mybatis.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.sankuai.meituan.waimai.money.charge.misc.CoreLauncher.main(CoreLauncher.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'chargeDao' defined in file [...ChargeDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/application-mybatis.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/application-mybatis.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1342)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(BeanNameAutoProxyCreator.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
... 35 more
```

The NullPointerException in line 80 of BeanNameAutoProxyCreator.java is in method getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean:

```java
if (this.beanNames != null) {
    for (String mappedName : this.beanNames) {
        if (FactoryBean.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
            if (!mappedName.startsWith(BeanFactory.FACTORY_BEAN_PREFIX)) {
                continue;
            }
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I found when the 'beanNames' has an un-null entry or has no entry, 'mappedName'  always be null, and so throws NullPointerException, why 'mappedName' is null ?

any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: I am not a Spring user, more of an AOP expert. But still I wonder why you create your own `BeanNameAutoProxyCreator` instead of letting Spring take care of creating proxies for you. What is the rationale behind that?

Comment: this code will be packaged into jar as infrastructure package for other service applications(eg:app1), the jar's function is to add an interceptor to some spring beans with a custom annotation in app1, and app1 need not to aware this - eg app1 need not to add interceptor to beans

Comment: How does that answer my question? Either it does not or I just don't know enough about Spring. Maybe someone else can make sense of your description. I definitely cannot. Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks.  If don't use BeanNameAutoProxyCreator, the app1(and other apps use this jar) must configure interceptor to bean/class, BeanNameAutoProxyCreator can create interceptor for these apps automatically